# Would an Iron Golem with Electricity Resistance be slowed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, monsters, damage-resistance

Iron Golem:

> A magical attack that deals electricity damage slows an iron golem (as the slow spell) for 3 rounds, with no saving throw.

If the golem had resistance to lightning to negate the spell damage, would it be slowed the same?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not the same thing, but the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on [Damage Reduction](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#damage-reduction), in part, says that

> Whenever damage reduction completely negates the damage from an attack, it also negates most special effects that accompany the attack, such as injury type poison, a monk’s stunning, and injury type disease. (292)

So, based on this, the DM has a choice: *either* resistance to electricity functions similarly enough to damage reduction that negating the electricity damage completely—so that the electricity damage *is not dealt* to the creature—likewise means the creature remains unaffected by any of the electricity effect's ancillary effects *or* because ignoring ancillary effects is unmentioned by [Resistance to Energy](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#resistance-to-energy) (298) the creature does, in fact, still suffer the electricity effect's ancillary effects.

A strict DM would likely rule the latter, but a persuasive player may sway a less strict DM toward the former.

In other words, the rules are silent on this specific case, probably not anticipating, for example, a wizard equipping her [iron golem](http://dndsrd.net/monstersG.html#iron-golem) (*Monster Manual* 136–7) with a [*ring of greater electricity resistance*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#ring-of-energy-resistance) (*DMG* 232) (44,000 gp; 0 lbs.).

Answer (score 1):

The iron golem is slowed even with resistance/immunity to electricity damage.

[Iron Golem](http://dndsrd.net/monstersG.html#iron-golem)s have Magic Immunity:

> Immunity to Magic (Ex): An iron golem is immune to any spell or spell-like ability that allows spell resistance. In addition, certain spells and effects function differently against the creature, as noted below.
>
> A magical attack that deals electricity damage slows an iron golem (as the slow spell) for 3 rounds, with no saving throw.
>
> (etc.)

[Energy Resistance](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#resistance-to-energy) is defined as:

> A creature with resistance to energy has the ability (usually extraordinary) to ignore some damage of a certain type each round, but it does not have total immunity.
>
> Each resistance ability is defined by what energy type it resists and how many points of damage are resisted. It doesn’t matter whether the damage has a mundane or magical source.
>
> When resistance completely negates the damage from an energy attack, the attack does not disrupt a spell. This resistance does not stack with the resistance that a spell might provide.

Generic Energy Immunity isn't defined, but Cold and [Fire](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#fire-immunity) are; the relevant bit in both is:

> A creature with fire immunity never takes fire damage. (etc; fire immunity inherently includes cold vulnerability)

Neither Resistance nor Immunity say anything about damage being reduced to 0 categorically negating additional effects of the source of the damage the way that [DR](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#damage-reduction) does.

Iron golems don't actually have [Spell Resistance](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#spell-resistance), so [Shocking Grasp](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shocking-grasp) still deals electricity damage, it's just that the golem is immune to it since it's from a spell that offers SR. Thus, the spell deals damage (that is ignored), thus it slows the golem.

Energy resistance and immunity both appear to work in much the same way: the damage is dealt but ignored, so Shocking Grasp still deals damage, so the golem is still slowed.